# pytorch 4d numpy array applying transfroms inside custom dataset

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

Inside my custom dataset, I want to apply `transforms.Compose()` to a NumPy array.

My images are in a NumPy array format with shape `(num_samples, width, height, channels)`.

How can I apply the follwoing transforms to the full numpy array?

`img_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Scale((224,224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.46, 0.48, 0.51], [0.32, 0.32, 0.32])
    ])`

My attempts are ending in multiple errors as the transforms accept a PIL image not a 4-d NumPy array.

```
from torchvision import transforms
import numpy as np
import torch

img_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Scale((224,224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.46, 0.48, 0.51], [0.32, 0.32, 0.32])
    ])

a = np.random.randint(0,256, (299,299,3))
print(a.shape)

img_transform(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All torchvision transforms operate on single images, not batches of images, hence a 4D array cannot be used.

Single images given as NumPy arrays, like in your code example, can be used by converting them to a PIL image. You can simply add [`transforms.ToPILImage`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage) to the beginning of the transformation pipeline, as it converts either a tensor or a NumPy array to a PIL image.

```py
img_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToPILImage(),
        transforms.Resize((224,224)),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.46, 0.48, 0.51], [0.32, 0.32, 0.32])
    ])
```

Note: [`transforms.Scale`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Scale) is deprecated in favour of [`transforms.Resize`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Resize).

In your example you used `np.random.randint`, which by default uses type int64, but images have to be uint8. Libraries such as OpenCV return uint8 arrays when loading an image.

```py
a = np.random.randint(0,256, (299,299,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thank you, so should I apply transforms to each image individually inside the custom dataset (4-d NumPy array)? I have a few million images (applying individually may become slow), do you think this is the way to go?

Comment: If you have a million images you should load them on demand in `__getitem__` of the dataset, then apply the transformations to the individual image. With this, the images can be loaded and transformed in background workers when using `DataLoader`, instead of having to do that in the main process.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So, inside `__getitem__`, a single `idx` for an image will be passed and I can apply the transforms there. As far as I read, `__getitem__` works with a single data point in the dataset if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Yes, it's a single image. But what I meant by loading the images on demand, is that you only keep the paths of the images in the dataset instead of all the images in memory, then load the image of the specified id and afterwards apply the transformation. Keeping a million images in memory could be problematic, or at least require a lot of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, for my case the original dataset is a big fat NumPy array, good idea, maybe I can make them back to images to save up some ram memory. For my case though, my ram doesn't seem to bother (128 gigs), besides my training happens on GPU so loading the full NumPy array is kinda fast for me.